# Can I achieve this?

Tags: civimember

For a client that owns a Club (120 members) that has also a restaurant, I need to create an area for the client with these features:

Admin side:

1. The admin should be able to create custom filed for the members (Adress 1, Adress 2, Company, etc. etc.)

"Budget" will be one of this custom field: every member has an amount of money when they join the club. Money they can use for restaurant etc. (Balance)

2. The admin will have a "Add Bill" function where he can add Bills from the restaurant for every member. The amount of the Bill will be then detracted to the Members budget.

Example: The member Kevin White has a budget of 1000 Euros, he goes to the restaurant and spends 20. Actualized budget: 980 Euros.

3. The admin will have a section called "Members" where he can see an overview of the members, and for each member he can see the "Balance".
4. The admin can send via email a report to the members with the Negativ "Balance".
5. The admin can send Info E-Mail to all the members.

Can I achieve this with your plugin?

Or maybe can I build something similar with your Plugin?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I certainly think you can achieve this with CiviCRM.

However, please do realise that CiviCRM is a full blown CRM with a lot of functionality. What you are describing here sounds suspiciously like a membership in CiviCRM rather than just adding custom fields.

I would certainly recommend reading the CiviCRM user guide: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/ and playing with the memberships to see if this suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Civi does not have a concept of 'Balance' so you would require some customisation to be able to reduce the amount by the value of the 'spend'.

The rest of what you are asking for sounds straightforward